# Two concurrent API calls updating data incorrectly in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, concurrency, race-condition, consistency

I have an API which either adds a new row or updates the row in a SQL Server table. If the `ID` of payload is greater than `0`, then it updates the table based on the given `ID`, otherwise it inserts a new row and returns the new `ID`.

Here is the sample SQL snippet:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 

SET @FETCHEDID = (SELECT ID FROM dbo.SAMPLETABLE WHERE ID = @ID)
    
IF @FETCHEDID > 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.SAMPLETABLE
    SET [AMOUNT] = @AMOUNT,
        [DATECHANGED] = @DATEADDED,
        [LASTCHANGEDBYID] = @ADDEDBYID,
    WHERE [ID] = @ID;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.SAMPLETABLE ([AMOUNT], [DATEADDED],[LASTCHANGEDBYID], [DATECHANGED])
    VALUES (@AMOUNT, @DATEADDED, @ADDEDBYID, @DATEADDED);
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

When there are two successive duplicate calls from UI to this API in quick succession with `ID = 0` then it ends up adding two rows in the database table.

Ideally the fist API call should have added a new row and the second one should have updated the row with new `ID` returned by first call.

The call is made from UI and the `ID` in payload can only be updated first successful call. This can be handled in UI too by avoiding the duplicate call. But I want to make sure that backend is also able to handle it.

The second API call is reading the stale value of `ID` from table before it is updated.

How can we ensure that second API call starts only after completion of first one.

Comment: The way i see it, this is pure frontend problem, you need some debounce or whatever to handle multiple posts

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem when using `READ COMMITTED` isolation.

The way you are doing this "Upsert" logic is [a well-known anti-pattern](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern). The locking is not being done correctly (it requires `UPDLOCK`) and it even if it was it would still be inefficient.

Instead, just `UPDATE` then check the row-count and conditionally `INSERT`.

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;  -- needed to clean up transaction.

BEGIN TRANSACTION; 

UPDATE dbo.SAMPLETABLE WITH (HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK)
SET AMOUNT = @AMOUNT,
    DATECHANGED = @DATEADDED,
    LASTCHANGEDBYID = @ADDEDBYID
WHERE ID = @ID;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    INSERT INTO dbo.SAMPLETABLE
      (AMOUNT, DATEADDED, LASTCHANGEDBYID, DATECHANGED)
    VALUES (@AMOUNT, @DATEADDED, @ADDEDBYID, @DATEADDED);

COMMIT;
```

If inserts are more likely than updates then you can flip it round.

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;  -- needed to clean up transaction.

BEGIN TRANSACTION; 

INSERT INTO dbo.SAMPLETABLE
  (AMOUNT, DATEADDED, LASTCHANGEDBYID, DATECHANGED)
SELECT @AMOUNT, @DATEADDED, @ADDEDBYID, @DATEADDED)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.SAMPLETABLE WITH (HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK)
    WHERE ID = @ID);

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    UPDATE dbo.SAMPLETABLE
    SET AMOUNT = @AMOUNT,
        DATECHANGED = @DATEADDED,
        LASTCHANGEDBYID = @ADDEDBYID
    WHERE ID = @ID;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Will this really help though, if frontend is posting ID = 0 twice, then backend can't do anything about it but just do an insert twice nicely

Comment: Yes of course it will help: you will get one insert and one update whatever happens. There is simply no way two inserts can happen using the above syntax. If you think differently, please explain, I'm sure Aaron would love to hear. The `HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK` hints ensure that the updated row is held *whether or not it exists*, same in the second version.

Comment: Usually frontend is not single threaded, if someone posts two requests, they both come in, and start doing their thing, ie. send @id = 0 to some procedure that runs your code. Sure, the actual db calls will wait for each other, but eventually you will still get two inserts.

Comment: Oh I see, well if the ID doesn't exist then obviously you want an insert. I think the intention here would be to use an existing ID. OP says "If the ID of payload is greater than 0, then it updates the table based on the given ID" so if you use an existing ID then you will never get an insert.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit hard to understand what OP wants, since he mixes IDs in his code. If he had some other way of identifying existing rows, then it would be enough with backend synchronization, but i think here he might need frontend ones as well

Comment: @Charlieface The second code snippet provided by you helps and is able to solve the issue. Also agreed that we need to handle this scenario at frontend too for an effective resolution.